# Spread does not activate when restoring minimised windows across different workspace

Tags: unity, 11.10

I have recently upgraded to 11.10 and am now trying to figure out how to use the Unity interface.  I am having problems restoring minimised windows when I have more than one window for any given application open on different workspaces.  This is what I am trying to do:

- Step 1: Launch a new terminal window
- Step 2: Switch to a different workspace
- Step 3: Launch a new terminal window on the new workspace
- Step 4: Minimise this terminal window
- Step 5: Click on the terminal icon in the unity dock

When I perform the last step nothings happens, unless I use Unity 2D in which case I get the expected spread and I can select a terminal window.  Is this a bug or a feature?

Answer (score 1):

This is a bug that at least here has been fixed with the upcoming unity upgrade -4.24.0-0ubuntu1

Here's the bug report I have  on this
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity/+bug/838055